# FormsAuthentication cookie not setting UserData values

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, forms-authentication

I've accidentally jumped into the world of cookies and am trying to understand what's going on.  I have a web app developed in Visual Studio 20120/C# using FormsAuthentication.  When I first developed the app, I created a few fields to store in the authentication cookie: personID, firstName, and admin, the string looks like this: 777|Jimmy|1.  Everything has worked well since then.  Now I've added a fourth field to the end of the blur called "secBlur". When I do this and try to retrieve the value of secBlur, it tells me the array range is out of bounds because the earlier version of the cookie did not contain this field...makes sense.  I've spent the past couple of days trying to rewrite the validity check for my cookie, and I thought I had everything figured out.  However, when I go to write the new userData string into the cookie, it doesn't appear to be doing it.  My code is below, I'll try to walk through what I'm doing...

In the page_load of my master page, the first thing I'm doing is making a call to a cookie class I created to check that the cookie is the correct version:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated) 
        {
            authCookie ac = new authCookie();

            ac.validate();

            LoginName ct = (LoginName)loginStatus.FindControl("HeadLoginName");

            if (ct != null)
            {
                formValues fv = new formValues();

                ct.FormatString = fv.firstName;
            }
        }
    }
```

My entire cookie class is below.  In the Validate method I'm checking for the existence of the cookie and then checking to see that it is the correct version and that userData exists.  If it's not the correct version or userData does not exist I call the getUserData method to retrieve the most current info for this year, create a new ticket, store the ticket into the cookie, and then save the cookie.  I **think** the line saving the cookie is the problem, but I'm not sure.

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Contexts;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace DMC.Classes
{
    public class authCookie
    {
        public void cookiePrep(Login LoginUser)
        {
            string userData = "unknown|unknown";

            // Concat the values into a single string to pass into the cookie
            userData = getUserData(LoginUser.UserName);

            // Create the cookie that contains the forms authentication ticket
            HttpCookie authCookie = FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(LoginUser.UserName, LoginUser.RememberMeSet);

            // Get the FormsAuthenticationTicket out of the encrypted cookie
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
            FormsAuthenticationTicket newTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(3,
                                                                                ticket.Name,
                                                                                ticket.IssueDate,
                                                                                ticket.Expiration,
                                                                                LoginUser.RememberMeSet,
                                                                                userData,
                                                                                ticket.CookiePath);

            // Manually add the authCookie to the Cookies collection
            authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newTicket);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(authCookie);

            string redirUrl = FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(LoginUser.UserName, LoginUser.RememberMeSet);

            if (redirUrl == null)
                redirUrl = "../default.aspx";

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(redirUrl);
        }

        public string getUserData(string userID)
        {
            string userData = "";

            // Grab this user's firstname, personID, and Admin status
            string mySQL = "exec get_adBasicInfo @userName";
            string cf = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DistrictAssessmentDWConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(cf);
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(mySQL, connection);

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", userID);

            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                    userData = string.Concat(dr["personID"], "|", dr["firstName"], "|", dr["secBlur"]);
            }

            dr.Close();

            return userData;
        }

        public void validate()
        {
            HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

            if (authCookie != null)
            {
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

                /**********************************************************************************************************************
                 * Version 3: Added the secBlur field onto the userData string to see if logged in user needs to have sensitive       *
                 *              data blurred out (0: Normal; 1: Blur Sensitive Data                                                   *
                 **********************************************************************************************************************/
                if ((ticket.Version != 3) || (ticket.UserData == ""))
                {
                    string userData = getUserData(ticket.Name);

                    FormsAuthenticationTicket newAuthTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(3,
                                                                                            ticket.Name,
                                                                                            ticket.IssueDate,
                                                                                            ticket.Expiration,
                                                                                            ticket.IsPersistent,
                                                                                            userData,
                                                                                            ticket.CookiePath);
                    authCookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(newAuthTicket);
                    HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(authCookie);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

At this point control passes back out to the load_page function of my master page and attempts to retrieve the firstName of the user from the cookie by calling my formValues class, below:

```
using DMC.Classes;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace DMC.Classes
{
    public class formValues : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        public string firstName = getFirstName();
        public string personID = getPersonID();
        public string secBlur = getSecBlur();

        private static string getUserDataString(int ix)
        {
            string retValue = "";

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpCookie authCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

                if (authCookie != null)
                {
                    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

                    if (ticket != null)
                    {
                        string[] userData = { "" };

                        char[] delimiterChar = { '|' };
                        userData = ticket.UserData.Split(delimiterChar);

                        retValue = userData[ix];
                    }
                }
            }

            return retValue;
        }

        private static string getFirstName()
        {
            string firstName = getUserDataString(1);

            return firstName;
        }

        private static string getPersonID()
        {
            string personID = getUserDataString(0);

            return personID;
        }

        private static string getSecBlur()
        {
            string secBlur = getUserDataString(2);

            return secBlur;
        }
    }
}
```

On attempting to getFirstName, I'm getting an error in the getUserDataString method when attempting to set the retValue because the userData array is empty.  So can somebody please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In my authCookie class, I changed from:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.SetCookie(authCookie);
```

to

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Add(authCookie);
```

I'm not a fan of this though, because from what I read, if the cookie already exists, this does not overwrite the cookie, it will just create a duplicate. But I've been playing around and it's the only thing that seems to work.  If somebody has a better solution, please share!!